# Close popup window upon button click

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, popup, popupwindow

I have used the below script to open a popup window of woocommerce product.
I am looking forward to close this window automatically as I will click on "Add to Cart" Button.
Can someone help me to achieve this task, please?

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
 function pop1(){
     window.open(
       'https://www.veggietiffin.co.uk/product/flextiffin-plan'
       ,'popwin'
       ,'width=640
       , height=480'
     );
 }
// ]]></script>
<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="pop1()">Flex Tiffin Day 1</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Formatted code and cleaned title

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code just change the button class to the class on your site have fun

```
  <script>
    function pop1() {

      //wrapping the popup inside a variable
      var popup = window.open('https://www.veggietiffin.co.uk/product/flextiffin-plan', 'popwin', 'width=640, height=480');


      //add event listner to add to cart button
      document.getElementsByClassName('your class here').addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.close(popup);
      });

    }

  </script>
```